Equivalence to SQLCODE & SQLERRM, but for OS Errors?
I'm trying to catch an OS Error message just like when we catch SQL Error Messages.
An example of this error could be SP2-0310: Unable to open file: "file name".

I would normally just use variables SQLCODE & SQLERRM to do so, but is there a way to do it for OS?
I already tried just using SQLERRM, but it throws nothing of relevancy:


Edit 2024 Aug 29th 09:19 utc-6
Just to highlight one thing: this SQL script is intended to run SQL queries using SQLcl & report back some runtime data (e.g. how much time it took).  But in order to not spool the entire SQL extract in the screen, I need to use SET TERMOUT ON / OFF.
The expectation is to actually see if an SQL query failed because someone typed in the wrong directory + name. But the aim is not to exit the session, as I would need to login multiple times: I don't believe WHENEVER OSERROR will help, because it is either EXIT or CONTINUE (do nothing).
For instance, with SQLCODE I can create a BEGIN - PUT_LINE - END with the error.


As @MTO said, these "OS errors" are detected by the SQL*Plus client and you can't react to them from inside the DB. (A BEGIN..END block is PL/SQL code that runs inside the DB.) The WHENEVER OSERROR facility is very restricted: CONTINUE just skips the offending line (usually an @script line) and goes on with the execution of the next one. If you want to keep using scripts (OS files) and you want a finer control, you'll need to do it directly at the OS level (using shell scripts, etc).

You could write a simple shell script wrapper that that will call one single SQL script. If the SQL script doesn't exists (or fails,.etc), the wrapper will call a separate (and always existing) "handling" script (or some PL/SQL code stored in the DB).

Right, we just use shell scripting to examine the output of our sqlplus session and make decisions from there.

Hi, I've no experience using shell (I'm assuming you talk about PowerShell), so please apologize if my question makes no sense. Today within the SQL script I pass down information, namely SQL path & name, & Spool Output path & name. When I typed "sql /nolog" in a PowerShell window, it opened a CMD, so I'm not sure I can pass down variables, can I?

The SQL*Plus client will pre-process your script and split it into statements and will either:

Process SQL*Plus commands on the client; or
Send SQL and PL/SQL commands for the database to evaluate.

ORA- errors are generated by the database and can be handled in PL/SQL by using BEGIN ... EXCEPTION WHEN error_type THEN ... END;
SP2- errors are generated by the SQL*Plus client before anything is sent to the database. In this case, you have asked the SQL*Plus client to open the file fs\fds.sql and the file does not exist on the client.
If you want the SQL*Plus client to do something when an OS error occurs you can use the WHENEVER OSERROR command before you try to call the non-existent script and then the client will process the handler you define in that command.
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT
@"&RFLD.&RFLE..&REXT."

WHENEVER OSERROR CONTINUE
@path\to\other.sql

Note: this is a command for the SQL*Plus client application (and other client applications that support the same syntax) and is not a command that is processed on the database and is meaningless to client applications that do not support the SQL*Plus syntax.

Hi! I added some more context. Hopefully it makes sense, thanks!

@FelipeVidal There is no other way to handle client-side OS errors within the SQL*Plus client. You can see the SQL*Plus commands listed here and there is nothing else that can be used. The database will NEVER see client-side errors as they occur before sending the command to the database so any SQL or PL/SQL commands are irrelevant to your problem (as its not an exception that occurs on the database).

You either use WHENEVER OSERROR ...  or you handle it on your OS using some shell scripting to call the SQL*Plus client application and catch the OS exception in the shell script.
